# null pointer after intent in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a first activity for my splash screen and second activity that extend from activity that is my navigation drawable. so the problem is when I go to second activity and go to function that handle navigation position I get null pointer error.I have no idea why is behave like that.

this is my first activity codes:

```
package com.example.uniapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
Button next;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);



next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Description.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


    }
});

}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////some function this functions is not use
public int testdb()
{
    int count = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase mydb;
    try {
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "asdasddasds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        MyDatabase MyDataBase = new MyDatabase(this);
        mydb = MyDataBase.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM news",null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        cursor.moveToNext();
        String TempTest = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
        if(!TempTest.equals(""))
            count = 5;
        if(cursor != null)
        {
            //cursor.moveToFirst();
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "null!!!!!!!!!!"  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }



        cursor.close();
        mydb.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "database 11 done : " + count , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: exception daa base
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data error 1 : " + 0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

and this is my second activity codes:

```
package com.example.uniapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class Description extends DrawableNav implements OnItemClickListener {

int drawableposition;
MyArray myarray;
MyDatabase MyDataBase;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
int count = 0;
ListView MyList;
TextView showInfo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*inflaste layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //inflate your activity layout here!
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newdescription, null, false);
    mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);


    //////////////////////////////intilitize list view
    MyList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    showInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_uniInfo);

    //////////////////////////////get intent
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //count = intent.getIntExtra("db", 0);





}
//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<cases
public void SelectItem(int possition) {

    drawableposition = possition;
    if(possition != 0)
        showInfo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    switch (possition) {

    case 0 :

        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<test for exception");
        showInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); ///get null pointer here by all codes

        break;
   case 1:
          ////////////// codes work well
   break;
     }
  }
}
```

I even more confuse that some Toast work there.when I Toast there it has no problem but i cant make the textview Visible.

09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067): Process: com.example.uniapp, PID: 28067
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.uniapp/com.example.uniapp.Description}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at com.example.uniapp.Description.SelectItem(Description.java:94)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at com.example.uniapp.DrawableNav.onCreate(DrawableNav.java:109)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at com.example.uniapp.Description.onCreate(Description.java:61)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
09-13 22:16:48.708: E/AndroidRuntime(28067):    ... 11 more

and also i found out if i erase this code from my navigation drawable activity all things work well

this is the code:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           SelectItem(0);
}
```

this code call the action of first position when activity first time appear

Comment: please post the logcat error ?

Comment: @AhmadAlkhateeb i just add the logcat. thx ;)

Comment: where **showInfo** is ? and what should it do ?

Answer (score 0):

My guest is that, You are not initializing your mDrawerLayout in onCreate method, may be the exception is raising from the below line in onCreate method...!

```
mDrawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
```

Please initilialize the mDrawerLayout first, like below,

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById (R.id.your_drawer_layout_id);
```

One morething you are not setting Content in activity like below,

```
setContentView(int);
```

Comment: thx for responding. but i found where my problem is. but i dont figure out why is so like that.let me edit my question

Answer (score 0):

initilize **mDrawerLayout** and Please Try :

```
showInfo = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.show_uniInfo);
```

**Insted of:**

```
showInfo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_uniInfo);
```

Comment: I had test it and it does not respond unfortuantly. but thx any way